# Deleting Duplicate with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Need help with my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `numero_presentation_technique` FROM tab_num_tache ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$m_pres_tech = $donnees['numero_presentation_technique'];
```

So here i'm asking the server for Unique data from my table and after to display it on the page.

**Problem =>** It only shows the first data of the table and then repeats it all the time.
But when i do it using SQL request on the domain page, it works...
Thanks in advance!

When i loop the fetch =
      Array ( [0] => 0039NZR4 [numero_presentation_technique] => 0039NZR4 )
When i use mysqli_fetch_all() = shows just the number and repeats

Comment: Please add your code into your question....

Comment: Please don't use images to share code. They're not searchable, they can't be copy-pasted, and they offer poor accessibility. Instead, [edit] your question and copy the code as text into it. You can format it properly by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button, or Ctrl+K.

Comment: @elianero can you please provide some more detail

Comment: Loop the `fetch`... or show us where you are outputting the data.

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_all() function instead if you are confused in this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responces! 

mysqli_fetch_all() => didn't change anything
fetch looping        => didn't change anything

Comment: Is `[0] => 0039NZR4 [numero_presentation_technique] => 0039NZR4` the repeat you are talking about or `0039NZR4 ` is being displayed multiple times? If you dont specify the fetch method you get both dynamic and associative array returned. **Add** the code that displays the dups...

Comment: With the loop it repeats the whole line over and over, with  mysqli_fetch_all() just the number that is repeating

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the results and fetch

```
while($donnees =  mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    print_r($donnees);  echo "<br>";
}
```